# No notification with Observer & Observable

Tags: java, observable

My problem, by debugging, that is `notifyObservers();` function not called my update function in my view. In debugging, the `setChanged();` function pass a `true` and after the `notifyObservers();` function is not doing its job.

Here is my code :

Modele :

```
public final class Modele_Jeu extends Observable{

public Grille grille;
public Piece piece;

public Modele_Jeu(){

    this.grille = new Grille(22,10);
    this.piece = new Piece();

    this.piece.creer_pieces();
    this.init_piece_in_grille();

    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();

}

private void init_piece_in_grille(){


    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=3;j<8;j++)
        {
            this.grille.matrice[i][j]= 1; //this.piece.piececourante[0][i];
        }

    }
    System.out.print(this.piece.toString());
    System.out.print(this.grille.toString());


}  
}
```

Vue :

```
public class Vue_Jeu extends JFrame implements Observer{

Modele_Jeu jeu;

JPanel container = new JPanel ();

JPanel droite = new JPanel();
JPanel pan = new JPanel (new GridLayout(22,10));
JPanel gauche = new JPanel();

public Vue_Jeu(Modele_Jeu jeu1) {

    this.jeu=jeu1;
    jeu.addObserver(this);
    //jeu1.addObserver(this);

    build();
    this.pan.getComponent(100).setBackground(Color.red);

            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            super.windowClosing(arg0);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
            this.pack();


}


@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    int n=0;
    System.out.print("\n\n"+this.jeu.grille.toString());
    this.jeu.grille = (Grille) arg;
    for(int i =0; i<this.jeu.grille.getlongueur(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<this.jeu.grille.getlargeur(); j ++)
        {
            if(this.jeu.grille.matrice[i][j]!=0)
            {
                this.pan.getComponent(n).setBackground(Color.red);
            }    
            n++;
        }
    }
}  
}
```

Main :

```
public class Tetris {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Modele_Jeu modele1 = new Modele_Jeu();
    Vue_Jeu vue1 = new Vue_Jeu(modele1);
}
}
```

Comment: How do you expect it to work when you're calling them in the Modele_Jeu *constructor* before you register your observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you call `notifyObservers()` is in the `Modele_Jeu` constructor. By the time you add an observer to the object, that has already happened.

Or is there more code that isn't posted here?